# Java - Get Certificate Chain

Tags: java, validation, x509certificate, chain

I have a certificate encoded in Base64 ----- BEGIN
CERTIFICATE ----- 
MIIGezCCBWOgAwIBA ...., how to get the root and intermediate certificates that appear in the certification path from it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. You see, the certificate have an Issuer field, which has the issuer's subject.
You can compare that, or/and you can test the signature. Only the CA can verify the certificate's signature.
Something like this:

```
//load all the ca certificates and get their public keys
caCertificate.getIssuerDN().equals(caCertificate[i].getSubjectDN());
// OR/AND

try {
   verifySignature(certificate,
        caCertificate[i].getPublicKey());
    //issuer found
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // not the issuer
}
```

I didn't test the code, but you got the idea.

EDIT:

There are some classes in java that are specially made for validating a chain. one of them is the `CertPathBuilder` class. I am still researching on how to use it. I always create it with the wrong parameters, i suppose...

EDIT 2:

I am using something that was inspired by [this](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/).

good luck